# .htaccess rewrite problems 404 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using .htaccess to beautify my URLs. I use this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.shtml index.shtm

ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

However when I go to any URL without the .php extension it gives me a 404 error:

> /www/alltutories.comule.com/contact.php

But contact.php does exist on my server... I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: `/www/alltutories.comule.com/contact.php` is the file reported in the error log?

Answer (score 1):

I think `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is "contact.php", so `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\\.php` is "contact.php.php" which does not exists.

Comment: So then what should I change?

Comment: @Goombi he is accessing the resource without .php extension at the end, why should it be `contact.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

could you try something like, changing only this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ignore my last comment: now it always goes to the 404 page instead of the actual page...

Comment: I mean it redirects to the actual custom 404 page that I created instead of saying "there was also a 404 error in finding the 404 page".

Comment: then the rule is working right? because `ErrorDocument 404 /404` says that the 404 has no .php extension. this last error lies somewhere else probably

Comment: maybe a documentroot misplaced somewhere? the `RewriteCond` probably is unable to find the php file (test for now commenting that cond, you should see it working if that's the case)

Comment: If I remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` its back to the begin situation and if I remove the other condition nothing changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65977/discussion-between-simon-h-and-drc).